# Freeware Windows FTP client that allows credential inheritance

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, ftp

I'm looking for a freeware FTP client for Windows that allows the user to set credentials for a "group" of sites once and have each site within that group use (or "inherit") those credentials when connecting.

This would work similar to how Microsoft's [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) works.  In the attached screenshot we can see that the credentials used to connect to "ExampleServer" are inherited from the parent object, in this case the "ExampleGroup".

If no freeware software exists, I'd be interested in suggestions of shareware/commercial alternatives that offer this functionality.

[image: Screenshot of Remote Desktop Connection Manager]